# Why commutator subgroup is normal to G?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is a group and $G'$ is generated by $\{xyx^{-1}y^{-1}|x,y\in G\}$, then $G'\trianglelefteq G$ and  $G/G'$ is Abelian.

At first, I thought this is easy because I thought $g[x,y]g^{-1}=[gxg^{-1},gyg^{-1}]$. But it was a mistake. I could not prove that it is also subgroup of G and $G/G'$ is abelian. I need help.

Comment: $g[x,y]g^{-1}=[gxg^{-1},gyg^{-1}]$ is perfectly correct. And you don't need to prove that $G'$ is a subgroup, it is one by definition. As for the fact that $G/G'$ is abelian, try proving that commutators are trivial.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I proved that $G/G'$ is abelian. But why don' need to show that $G'$ is a subgroup? Then Is the Commutator 'subgroub' of $G$ already a subgroup of $G$ by just definition????

Comment: @김일희 No, I think the intention of Arnaud was: for **any** subset $\;S\;$ of a group $\;G\;$ , *by definition* $\;\langle S\rangle\;$ is the subgroup generated by elements of $\;S\;$ , and here $\;G'=\langle [g,h]\;:\;g,h\in G\rangle\;$ . When you say "subgroup generated by...", you already have a subgroup!

Comment: $G'$ is *defined* as the subgroup of $G$ generated by the commutators, so there is no need to prove it is a subgroup.

Comment: Ohhh I had forgotten what 'generated' means. I was so stupid... haha Everyone Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commutator subgroup of $G$ is the subgroup *generated* by the set $C$ of elements of the form $[x,y]=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$.

Suppose you have a subset $S$ with the property that, for every $g\in G$ and every $x\in S$, $gxg^{-1}\in S$. Then the subgroup $H$ generated by $S$ is normal in $G$.

Indeed, an element of the subgroup $H$ is of the form
$$
x=x_1^{a_1}x_2^{a_2}\dots x_n^{a_n}
$$
where $a_i=\pm1$ and $x_i\in S$, for $i=1,2,\dots n$. Then, if $g\in G$, we clearly have
$$
gxg^{-1}=(gx_1g^{-1})^{a_1}(gx_2g^{-1})^{a_2}\dots(gx_ng^{-1})^{a_n}
$$
so $gxg^{-1}\in H$, because $gx_ig^{-1}\in S$, for $i=1,2,\dots,n$.

In the case of the commutator subgroup,
$$
g[x,y]g^{-1}=[gxg^{-1},gyg^{-1}]\in C
$$
so, by the remark above, $G'=\langle C\rangle$ is normal in $G$.